# Why the Accuracy value of model changed when I used different training platform?

Tags: gpu, google-colaboratory, precision, object-detection

Why the accuracy of deep learning model changed although the hyper-parameters still same (#epoch, #Batch, lr and datasets)

First experiment has trained on Colap Pro plan and get Average Precision AP 81%.

Second experiment has trained on colab with free plan and get Average Precision 76%.

Is the GPU size effect on the Performance results?